# Is there a Salesforce solution to Filter or Limit Aura iteration?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, iteration

I am iterating through a list of items as follows

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.objWrap}" var="item" indexVar="idx">
...
...
...
 </aura:iteration>
```

I also want to have a load more button after this that shows an additional 10 items.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0); onclick="myfunction()"">Load More</a>
```

Is it possible to filter the iteration to show a set amount, then when I click the load more, it loads another 10? Is there a way through salesforce that would make this easier?

Thanks

Comment: Are you loading next set of 10 items when user clicks on the load more button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply use aura:if and check if you indexVar is smaller or equals 10. I think it should look something like this.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.objWrap}" var="item" indexVar="idx">
    <aura:if value="{!idx < 10}">
        <a href="javascript:void(0); onclick="otherfunction()"">{!item.Something__c}</a>
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if value="{!idx == 10}">
        <a href="javascript:void(0); onclick="myfunction()"">Load More</a>
    </aura:if>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is simple and works

Comment: You're very welcome Angelo.

Answer (score 4):

Just for reference, here is verified working code - it's very similar to that shown above, but I fixed a couple of issues:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.objWrap}" var="item" indexVar="idx">
  <aura:if isTrue="{!lessthan(idx,10)}">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="otherfunction()">{!item}</a>
  </aura:if>
  <aura:if isTrue="{!idx == 10}">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myfunction()">Load More</a>
  </aura:if>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: You could improve it using else

Comment: <aura:component>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.truthy}">
    True
    <aura:set attribute="else">
      False
    </aura:set>
  </aura:if> 
</aura:component>

Comment: Actually, no - there are three conditions here. If less than 10, render stuff. If 10, render "Load More" and an implied Else - don't render anything.

Comment: You are right, it depends on the content, I thought that if 10 is the last value of the objWrap, you could to render it in the else condition

Comment: Casper's answer is best but here is a way to do the expression with the < operator.   <aura:if isTrue="{! (inx * 1) &lt; v.listLimit }">